# Setting up NSFetchedResultsController and Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a ManagedObject that I am trying to monitor with NSFetchedResultsController. I am wanting to have to the delegate only trigger when the object itself has been modified or added or deleted. The delegate it getting called when I modify any of the objects in the objects relationships. Here is the code for setting up the object and the code for updating the object.

```
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

// Set Enitity.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Workgroup" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController * aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
[aFetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

Here is the code for updating the main object and child object

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.background", NULL);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"Workgroup"];

    // Add x Workgroups
    for(int a = 0;a < 10;a++)
    {
        Workgroup * workgroup = [[PCSDataStorage sharedInstance] workgroupWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:a]];
        [workgroup setName:[self genRandStringLength:10]];

        // Add x Files
        for(int b = 0;b < 1000;b++)
        {
            File * file = [workgroup fileWithID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",b]];

            NSError * error;
            if(![[PCSDataStorage sharedInstance] save:&error])
                NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
        }
    }
});
```

It there a better place to call the save method I put it at the end of the first loop but the performance was really bad.

Comment: Would you like to track changes only in one specific object?

Comment: I only want to monitor changes to the workgroups themselves. I don't want it to trigger the delegate if I modify a file in a workgroup because none of the data for that workgroup has changed.

Comment: Then your in luck, as a FRC won't track changes in related objects (only if you set a new related object for a relationship)

Comment: Actually now that I look at it I believe there may be a bug with NSFetchedResultsController because it is triggering the delegate every time I call save but only when there is only one item in workgroups once I have added one workgroup it works like I want it to only calling the delegate to update the name.